# How can I fetch and extract a tgz file in a single command?

Tags: bash, tar

I often need to fetch tgz files, decompress them, and then delete the tgz.
How can I do all three steps with one simple command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can use:

```
curl <url> | tar xz
```

Or put in your bashrc:

```
function ctxz {
   curl $1 | tar xz
}
```

and just use:

```
ctxz <url>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wget http://site/path/file.tgz -O - | tar -zxvf -
```